# Passing in a vector as a parameter with set values

Tags: c++, object, vector, constructor, parameter-passing

**Overview:**

I'm making a video game in C++, and I need to have a list of items that an enemy can drop, and the drop chances of each item, but different enemies might have different number of items that they can drop.
I have an ActorDefinition class whose constructor defines all the stats&things about an enemy.

**So here's the problem:**

How do I pass in a vector to an object constructor with arbitrarily defined values?

For example this is what I want to be able to do as if I were using static arrays:

```
//first array is item types to drop, second array is drop chances as percentages
ActorDefinition("actorname", [10, 2], [50, 90]);
```

This is nice, and it only takes up one line. But I cant do this because I need dynamic sizes, thus I want to use a vector.

So I need to essentially do this, (which works and accomplishes what I want, but is very messy):

```
vector<int> drops;
drops.push_back(10);
drops.push_back(2);
vector<int> dropChances;
dropChances.push_back(50);
dropChances.push_back(90);
ActorDefinition("actorname", drops, dropChances);
```

Is there a way to do this without adding separate lines of code like above? (I have so many actor definitions and so many items that if I were to do this for each one, it will pile up a ton of lines of annoying code) creating a vector and pushing back each index with my values?

Edit- Fixed the typo in my example code

Comment: Ultimately I would think you wouldn't hardcode these values, but store them persistently and then read them in?  In that case, it just becomes a matter of reading a file or database or what have you and looping on each entry.

Comment: Thats a good point, I've been using hard-coded values in my program for testing purposes mostly. Passing in via file is most likely the best option here, but now I just really want to know if anything like this is possible in C++.

Comment: What gives you the impression that you can write static arrays like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using C++11's [direct list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#direct-list-initialization) syntax you can write this:

```
vector<int> drops{10,2};
vector<int> dropChances{50,90};
ActorDefinition("actorname", drops, dropChances);
```

Or even more succinct, while not necessarily more readable:

```
ActorDefinition("actorname", vector<int>{10,2}, vector<int>{50, 90});
```

And finally, if your function overloads can be resolved unambiguously, you could even use [copy list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and call it like this:

```
ActorDefinition("actorname", {10,2}, {50, 90});
```

Use this final form with care though. For example, this works:

```
void func(vector<int> a);
func({1,2});
```

but adding another `func` overload breaks the `func({1,2})` call:

```
void func(vector<int> a);
void func(set<int> a);
func({1,2});//ERROR! Call to func is ambiguous!
```

(Note all the above examples also fix the typo you had in the repeated `push_back`s in your code when you added `50` and `90` to `drops` instead of `dropChances` :))

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! Oh lol, I didn't even see the typo :P

Answer (score 3):

You may define the function like:

```
typedef vector<int> vi; // handy while declaring a lot of them

int ActorDefinition(string name, vi vec1, vi vec2)
{
    // body here
}
```

And may call this way:

```
ActorDefinition("someName", {10, 20}, {30, 50, 60, 70});
```

Comment: Agree... but no need for the typedef stuff :-)  It just makes the code more complicated to read. Requires -std=c++11 I think.

Comment: @nielsen: `typedef` wasn't urgent here, I agree with you. But it doesn't need c++11. And I think sometimes it makes the code easier to read if you are declaring a lot of containers here and there which is kind of relevant to the question. That's why used it..! :-)

Comment: @ minarmahmud - With regard to typedef I do agree that it can be useful but using vi for vector<int> is not useful. Maybe `typedef vector<int> vectorInt` could be but that doesn't save much typing. Anyway - are you sure that this doesn't require c++11? It does with my installation...

Comment: @nielsen: Sorry, my bad.. `typedef` needs c++11. Going to mention it in the answer. Thanks..!

Comment: @ minarmahmud - not the typedef... the initializer-list, I think. But never mind, your answer were the first to solve the problem :-) Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

define your function like this:

```
void ActorDefinition(
    const std::string& actorname,
    const vector<int>& drops,
    const vector<int>& dropChances);
```

Comment: Not sure this really helps matters, since it won't allow construction of these elements with just one line.  It will take only 1 like to call `ActorDefinition`, but multiple likes to set up the parameters for that call.

Comment: The problem I'm having is not that I need to reference an existing vector, but that I want to construct an array inline in the constructor, like using vector(10, 100) which constructs a vector of 10 with values 100, except I need to use my own defined values, not 100

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
class make_vector {
public:
  typedef make_vector<T> my_type;
  my_type& operator<< (const T& val) {
    data_.push_back(val);
    return *this;
  }
  operator std::vector<T>() const {
    return data_;
  }
private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

So you can construct vector using this function:

```
std::vector<int> v = make_vector<int>() << 50 << 90;
```

So in your case:

```
ActorDefinition("name", make_vector<int>() << 50 << 90, make_vector<int>() << 10 << 20);
```

In C++11 you can simply use:

```
std::vector<int> v { 34,23 };
ActorDefinition("name", {10, 20}, {30, 50});
```